# A strange phenomenon when I read and update an Access database

Tags: c#, web-services, ms-access

I have an Access database that has field named [TermNum] (AutoNumber).

I try to register terminals in the Access database (via my WebService C#) like this:

```
using (Conn = new OleDbConnection(Connect))
{
    Conn.Open();

    SQL = "select TermNum from TermNumTbl where DeviceID = '" + DeviceID + "'";
    dsView = new DataSet();
    adp = new OleDbDataAdapter(SQL, Conn);
    adp.Fill(dsView, "TermNumTbl");
    adp.Dispose();

    try
    {
        iTermNumTmp = Convert.ToInt32(dsView.Tables[0].Rows.Count);
    }
    catch
    {
        iTermNumTmp = 0;
    }

    if (iTermNumTmp >= 1) 
    {
        return (Convert.ToInt32(dsView.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString().Trim()));
    }
    else
    {
        int ID;
        SQL = "insert into TermNumTbl (DeviceID,IP) values (@DeviceID,@DeviceIP)";

        using (OleDbCommand Cmd4 = new OleDbCommand(SQL, Conn))
        {
            Cmd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DeviceID", DeviceID);
            Cmd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DeviceIP", DeviceIP);
            Cmd4.ExecuteNonQuery();

            SQL = "Select @@Identity";
            Cmd4.CommandText = SQL;
            ID = (int)Cmd4.ExecuteScalar();
        }
        return ID;
    }
}
```

if the terminal exist = return his number

if the terminal not exist = insert his number to data base and return this number

The problem is that sometimes it does not work and I get this error:

> A DataTable named 'TermNumTbl' already belongs to this DataSet

Comment: Have you tried making dsView local within the Using (Conn = statement?  Can't see anything obvious that might be causing it if that doesn't work.

Comment: Some of the variable used in this block of code are not declared here. So I suppose that when two clients connects you could have some problems with the sharing of these variables. Why don't you simply declare the variable where you use them?

Answer (score 1):

It seems from your code that you have defined dsView somewhere outside the method (as a class member perhaps?). You are trying to select the same table into the same dataset. Define the dataset as needed as a local object. Change:

```
dsView = new DataSet();
```

to:

```
DataSet dsView = new DataSet();
```